# How to configure Apache to proxy exactly one file?

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

(I must be dense - I just can't figure out the Apache documentation on how to do this.)

To speed up some swf development I'm doing, I want to have my local machine fetch my local swf when I browse to our studio's test website. Just the one local swf only - with the rest pulled from the test website.

So I set up apache on port 80 with mod_proxy and proxy_http_module, then added an entry for HOSTS to say the test server is 127.0.0.1. What I need are the magical incantations to put in httpd.conf to say "every call requesting http://test/blah goes to 10.1.1.whatever EXCEPT http://test/blah/foo.swf which goes to c:\proj\foo.swf".

Can someone help with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple syntax for disallowing a particular URL from proxying:

```
ProxyPass /blah/foo.swf !
ProxyPass /blah http://10.1.1.whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

For the record here's what I ended up with, roughly:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName (testserver-dns)
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /path/to/swf !
    ProxyPass / http://10.1.2.3/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.1.2.3/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```